# Please tell me how to fill in the fields in the list that lies on the map

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have a map

```
Map<Id, List<ExpenseController.MonthRow>> monthsPerKeeper = new Map<Id, List<ExpenseController.MonthRow>>();
```

This is how she looks:
[image]

Right now I'm only showing the months ("monthNumber") that are full.
I need to fill in all the missing ("monthNumber") and the ("amount") field for that ("monthNumber") should be 0.

It should look like this:
[image]

I tried to get the value from the map by id (that is, the List)
but I don't know how to refer to the fields in this List to fill them in

```
for (Id c : monthsPerKeeper.keySet()) {
            if(monthsPerKeeper.containsKey(c)) {
                for (ExpenseController.MonthRow a : monthsPerKeeper.get(c)) {
                    
                    List<ExpenseController.MonthRow> monthsListAdd = new List<ExpenseController.MonthRow>();
                    for (Integer i = 1; i < 13; i++)  {

                        if (!monthsPerKeeper.get(c).monthNumber.containsKey(i)) {
                            ExpenseController.MonthRow row = new ExpenseController.MonthRow();
                            row.monthName = ExpenseController.monthNumbers.get(i);
                            row.amount = 0;
                            row.monthNumber = i;

                            monthsListAdd.add(row);
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why in first screenshot for 1st key the November appears twice (37 and 14)? Are they supposed to be unique?

Comment: I can shop in the same month on different days
11/01/2022 --- amount = 37
11/13/2022 --- amount = 14

I just did not indicate in my sheet the days

Comment: but for same contact you'd then want to aggregate it, right? In apex or in javascript but combined into 51? look how I did `SUM(Amount) ... GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH(CloseDate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you have `monthsListAdd` with say 5 dummy months and want to add it to the original list of 7 real months? Many ways to do it, seeing how your screenshot list is unsorted and really the gaps (no expenses this month) can be anywhere... I'd probably reverse the whole thing, start with 12 placeholders with 0 amounts and just update them as I go through list...

Anyway:

After that `for (ExpenseController.MonthRow a : monthsPerKeeper.get(c)) {` ends add this:

`monthsPerKeeper.get(c).addAll(monthsListAdd);`

I stil think you'll have this in rubbish order so maybe read up about "implements Comparable" to sort your list of helper objects after they're all added up?

---

**edit**

To make it cleaner I'd use a Map where key is month number and value is... well, if all you need is Amount then probably `Map<Integer,Decimal>` would do. If you'd want to display more - `Map<Integer, ExpenseController.MonthRow>` probably. Or you know, use the fact that List could have month numbers as indexes ;)

Consider this query (works in my sandbox and returns me something but with gaps. And that's OK)

```
SELECT CALENDAR_MONTH(CloseDate), SUM(Amount)
FROM Opportunity
WHERE CloseDate = THIS_YEAR AND IsWon = true AND Owner.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' AND Amount != null
GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH(CloseDate)
```

[image]

It's not even sorted - but I don't care.

```apex
Map<Integer, Decimal> myMap = new Map<Integer, Decimal>{
    1 => 0,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 0,
    4 => 0,
    5 => 0,
    6 => 0,
    7 => 0,
    8 => 0,
    9 => 0,
    10 => 0,
    11 => 0,
    12 => 0
};

for(AggregateResult ar : [SELECT CALENDAR_MONTH(CloseDate) m, SUM(Amount) a
    FROM Opportunity
    WHERE CloseDate = THIS_YEAR AND IsWon = true AND Owner.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' AND Amount != null
    GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH(CloseDate)]){
    myMap.put((Integer) ar.get('m'), (Decimal) ar.get('a'));
}

for(Integer i = 1; i < 13; ++i){
    System.debug(i + ' ' + DateTime.newInstance(2022,i,1).format('MMMM') + ': ' + myMap.get(i));
    // instead of debug you'd have your someList.add(new ExpenseController.MonthRow(...) or whatever
}
```

[image]

Comment: tell me how to check if there is already such a month in my list (and if there is no such month, I fill it in and add it to my Map)